# C : (standard input): Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2, execve

I try to recreate for a school project a program who emulate this type of command

> < infile grep g | wc -c > outfile

Someone i have any idea why i'm getting

> grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor

when running the following code

```
void    first_cmd_exec(t_command *cmd, char **envp, int *pipe_fd)
    {
        if ((cmd->fd = open(cmd->file, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
            perror_exit("open");
        if (close(pipe_fd[0]) == -1)        
            perror_exit("close 1 1st cmd");
        if (dup2(cmd->fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1)                   
            perror_exit("dup2 1st cmd");
        if (dup2(pipe_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
            perror_exit("dup2 1st cmd");
        if (close(pipe_fd[1]) == -1)
            perror_exit("close 2 1st cmd");
        if (execve(cmd->path_exec, cmd->tab_cmd, envp) == -1)
            perror_exit("execve 1st cmd");
    }

void    last_cmd_exec(t_command *cmd, char **envp, int *pipe_fd)
    {
        cmd = cmd->next;
        if ((cmd->fd = open(cmd->file, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
            perror_exit("open 2nd cmd");
        if (close(pipe_fd[1]) == -1)                            
            perror_exit("close 1 2nd cmd");
        if (dup2(cmd->fd, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)                 
            perror_exit("dup2 2nd cmd");
        if (dup2(pipe_fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)               
            perror_exit("dup2 2nd cmd");
        if (close(pipe_fd[0]) == -1)
            perror_exit("close 2 2nd cmd");
        if (execve(cmd->path_exec, cmd->tab_cmd, envp) == -1)
            perror_exit("execve 2nd cmd");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

void fork_it(t_list *list, char **envp)
    {
        pid_t       pid;
        pid_t       pid_2;
        t_command   *cmd;
        int         status;
        int         pipe_fd[2];
    
        cmd = list->first;
        if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1)
            perror_exit("pipe");
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            perror_exit("fork");
        else if (pid == 0)
            first_cmd_exec(cmd, envp, pipe_fd); 
        pid_2 = fork();
        if (pid_2 < 0)
            perror_exit("fork");
        else if (pid_2 == 0)
            last_cmd_exec(cmd, envp, pipe_fd);  
        else
        {
            close(pipe_fd[0]);
            close(pipe_fd[1]);
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            waitpid(pid_2, &status, 0);
        }
    
    }
```

If I understand correctly I have to use `dup2` to replace the standard input with my fd (my infile), so that my `execve` command can use it, and the same for my second command after the pipe so that it can write to my output file, but I must be missing something in my understanding or my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide complete code. Looks like you have most of it but need to see how the functions are called, ie, the `main`. Please ensure it is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, reduce the code by removing the `list` stuff as that is likely not relevant to the issue.

Comment: Seems like there may be a problem with `cmd->fd`.

Comment: You're executing the same `cmd` in the first command and last command.

Comment: @Barmar Nope is not the same i use a chain list for stock my data command

Comment: You have `cmd = list->first;`. You never reassign it for the second command.

Comment: i jump to the next element on my chain list with ```cmd = cmd->next```on the last_cmd_exec function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

> **EBADF**  fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for
> reading.

is grep's stdin open for reading?

```
void    first_cmd_exec(t_command *cmd, char **envp, int *pipe_fd)
    {
        if ((cmd->fd = open(cmd->file, **O_WRONLY**)) == -1)
```

no, you seem to be opening it write-only for some reason.

Comment: With ```O_WRONLY```it is not for write and read ?

Comment: @Med_Wo `WR` in `O_WRONLY` so it's short for _write_, so  `O_WRONLY` means _write only_.

Comment: Indeed my problem came from the fact that I created my FD only in writing thus during its reading by my execve, this last one did not have the authorization. Thanks @TedLyngmo